# How to send params through axios get request and receive them in flask?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, axios, get

I am trying to send 2 params to the backend through a get request that returns some query based on the params I send to the backend. I am using React.js front end and flask python backend.

My get request looks like this:

```
async function getStatsData() {
    const req = axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/stat/', {
        params: {
            user: 0,
            flashcard_id: 1
        },
        headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
    })
    const res = await req;
    return res.data.results.map((statsItem, index) => {
        return {
            stat1: statsItem.stat1,
            stat2: statsItem.stat2,
            stat3: statsItem.stat3,
            stat4: statsItem.user,
            key: statsItem.key
        }
    })
}
```

and then my route in the backend is this:

```
@app.route('/stat/<user>/<flashcard_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def stats(user, flashcard_id):
  def get_total_percent_correct(user):
    correct = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.responses WHERE guess = answer AND user_id = %s' % user)[0][0]
    total = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.responses WHERE user_id = %s' % user)[0][0]
    try:
        return round(float(correct)/float(total),3)*100
    except:
        print('0')
  
  def get_percent_correct_for_flashcard(user,flashcard_id):
    total = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.responses WHERE user_id = %s AND flashcard_id = %s' % (user, flashcard_id))[0][0]
    correct = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.responses WHERE flashcard_id = %s AND guess = answer AND user_id = %s' % (flashcard_id, user))[0][0]
    try:
        return round(float(correct)/float(total),3)*100
    except:
        print('0')

  def get_stats_for_flashcard(user_id, flashcard_id):
    attempts = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.responses WHERE user_id = %s AND flashcard_id = %s' % (user_id, flashcard_id))[0][0]
    correct = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.responses WHERE flashcard_id = %s AND guess = answer AND user_id = %s' % (flashcard_id, user_id))[0][0]
    missed = attempts - correct
    return attempts, correct, missed
  
  data = [{
    "stat1": get_total_percent_correct(user),
    "stat2": get_percent_correct_for_flashcard(user, flashcard_id),
    'stat3': get_stats_for_flashcard(user, flashcard_id),
    'user': user,
    'key':999
  }]

  return {"response_code" : 200, "results" : data}
```

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/stat/0/1 in my browser, the stats are shown correctly but the get request is not working because it says xhr.js:210          GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/stat/?user=0&flashcard_id=1 404 (NOT FOUND) . So clearly I'm not sending or receiving the params correctly. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

In your backend route you are expecting the values in url as dynamic segment, but from axios you are sending it as [query sring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

**Solution:**

You can modify the axios request like this to send the values as dynamic segment:

```
  const user = 0;
  const flashcard_id = 1;
  const req = axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/stat/${user}/${flashcard_id}`,{
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
})
```

**or** you can modify flask route like this if you need to recieve values from query params:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/stat/', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def stats():
    user = request.args.get('user')
    flashcard_id = request.args.get('flashcard_id')
```

Comment: I want the query strings to be dynamic though. Is that possible to do?

Comment: ok, thank you. I feel like I am much closer but now I'm getting this error: GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/stat/$%7Buser%7D/$%7Bflashcard_id%7D 404 (NOT FOUND) @Amjed Ali

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, thank you so much

Comment: @thealchemist7777  in axios get function, the link is enclosed in ` (Backtick) character not ' (Apostrophe).

Answer (score 0):

Send the parameters like this:

```
 const req = axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/stat/${user}/${flashcard_id}`)
```

and in Flask you receive the parameters like this:

```
@app.route('/stat/<user>/<flashcard_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def stats(user, flashcard_id):
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
@app.route('/axios_to_flask',methods=['GET',"POST"])
def register():
  print(request.get_json())
  return jsonify({'message':'here is your responce'})
```

Check out [this](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-print-data-in-an-axios-call-to-flask) guide